# Class Diagram VS2015RC 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to generate a class diagram using VS2015 RC1 but that particular file template is not available. See full list of template. Is this type of template will be available on this release?

[image: VS2015 templates].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nax, I found out that those type of file are not supported yet in VS2015 Preview, What I did was open a vs2013 and create an empty project, add the files and create the diagram there, this work for because the code that I have in my new project are just POCO classes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this may be a bug.
Work-ground is create text file and put following code in it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClassDiagram MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1">
</ClassDiagram>
```

Rename it as "your-diagram.cd"
Put it in your project. any your are done!